# Creating a disk image (.dmg) from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, osx-snow-leopard, diskimage

Is there any library to create a disk image from Cocoa, or is it only possible through Finder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do it *directly* from Cocoa (though there might be one) but there is another way. The [`hdiutil`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html) tool can be used from the Terminal, and you can call it from your program as well. Here's a sample usage for creating a disk image from a folder:

```
hdiutil create -fs HFS+ -volname "Volume Name" \
               -srcfolder "/path/to/source/directory" "path/to/filename.dmg"
```

Seems that http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/152742-disc-image-apis.html describes the same problem.

Comment: This is the path I had to go down when I wanted to automate DMG creation from my app. It's not all too painful, but it feels like it could crumble easily with the next release of OS X.

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if there was a Cocoa API to use, but the good news is that `hdiutil` has been backwards compatible, and will likely continue to be.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `hdiutil` tool, perhaps with the aid of NSTask.